# The linear operator in $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \lambda u$ is not bounded, but the linear operator in $A u = \lambda u$ is bounded, why?

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations, operator-theory

Let $A: R \rightarrow R$ is a linear operator, satisfying $A u = \lambda u$, where $\lambda \in R$, is bounded, and has norm $\|A\| = |\lambda|$.

$\frac{\partial }{\partial x}: C^{\infty}([0,1])\rightarrow C^{\infty}([0,1])$ is also a linear operator, satisfying $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \lambda u$, where $\lambda \in R$ is not bounded, why?

My confusion comes from Example 5.13, Example 5.14 in Hunter's applied analysis.

Comment: $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ is defined on the whole space and its norm must take into account all $u$ with a norm of 1. The equation $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \lambda u$ is not a definition of the derivative. It is an equation satisfied by the eigenstates $u$ of the operator.

Comment: No, $\frac\partial{\partial x}$ is**not** defined by $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\lambda u$.

Comment: Thanks, I  changed `defined by` to `satisfying`

Comment: If you want us to understand what you mean by your last sentence, you should explain what those exercises are about. Not everybody has that book in their library.

Comment: Consider $u_n(x) = \sqrt{2} sin(n\pi x)$. What is the norm of $u_n$ and its derivative?

Comment: They explain in the examples you referenced. What was confusing about the explanation?

Comment: @Paul $\|u_n\| = \sqrt{2}$, $\frac{\partial u_n}{\partial x} = \sqrt{2}n\pi cos(n\pi x)$

Comment: @cmk The logical which is given in the book is that for the second case (differential operator), the $\lambda$ can be arbitrarily large, hence not bounded, but then this logic should apply to the first case also.

Comment: In the first case $\lambda$ is a fixed number. In your comment $\|u_n\| = \sqrt{2}$ (should be 1 I think) and $\frac{\partial u_n}{\partial x} = \sqrt{2}n\pi cos(n\pi x)$ . The norm of $\frac{\partial u_n}{\partial x}$ depends on n if you calculate it, it is not a constant for all $u_n$.

Comment: @Paul I mean the sup norm over $x \in [0,1]$, thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Oh yes, sorry. Drop the $\sqrt{2}$ then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify the examples in Hunter, the operators in question are $A:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $D:C^\infty([0,1])\rightarrow C^\infty([0,1])$ given by $$Ax=ax,$$ where $a\in\mathbb{R}$ is fixed and $$Du(x)=u'(x).$$ The former operator is bounded since, for any non-zero real $x$, $|Ax|/|x|=|a|.$ The operator norm is the supremum over such quotients, and since the quotient is constant in $x$, operator norm is just $|a|$.

The latter operator is not bounded. On a *minor* variation of Hunter's example, take $u_n(x)=e^{nx}$, where $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Then, $$\|Du_n\|/\|u_n\|=n\rightarrow \infty\text{ as }n\rightarrow\infty.$$ The operator norm is the supremum of such quotients over all non-zero smooth $u$, which we see cannot be finite.

Comment: Thanks, looking back I feel that my question was silly, but I guess I am gonna not delete this post as who knows someone else might have this silly confusion!

Comment: @amitoz Plenty of people will have similar confusions when they see this material for the first time, so I agree with your assessment!